# Pushing new files to specific branch in existing repo

Tags: git, github

I have an existing repo. I want to push some new files into the non-master branch of my repo called `otherbranch`

I tried

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "second commit"
git remote add origin http://github.com/myusername/abc/tree/otherbranch
```

But `git checkout otherbranch` gives

```
error: pathspec 'otherbranch' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

and `git push origin otherbranch` gives

```
error: src refspec otherbranch does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/myusername/abc/tree/otherbranch'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `git fetch`, then `git checkout otherbranch`. Fetch will download refs from origin - otherwise your local working copy won't know about otherbranch.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch

EDIT

As @anoe pointed out, the origin url is wrong as it contains the branch name. You need to fix the incorrect origin by doing

`git remote set-url origin https://github.com/myusername/abc.git`

Then do fetch, checkout, commit, push etc.

Comment: `git fetch` gave `fatal: repository 'http://github.com/myusername/abc/tree/otherbranch/' not found`

Comment: You're right - the origin location is wrong, it should look something like `https://github.com/myusername/abc.git`. It shouldn't include any branch names. (Credit to @anoe for noticing the problem with the origin.) You'll still need to fetch once you've set up the correct origin.

Comment: when I type `git remote add origin https://github.com/myusername/abc.git` it says `fatal: remote origin already exists.`. When I try `git fetch` it says `fatal: repository 'https://github.com/myusername/abc' not found`

Comment: You'd probably need to do `git remote remove origin` and then `git remote add origin https://github.com/myusername/abc.git` again. Git won't let you add multiple remotes with the same name.

Comment: ok I tried that and then `git fetch` and then `git checkout otherbranch`. When I then try `git push origin otherbranch` I get an error. I then tried `git pull origin otherbranch` but I got errors about  `Automatic merge failed`, such as `Auto-merging src/somefile.txt
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in src/somefile.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.`

Comment: Looks like you're getting into conflict territory which might be a separate issue. At this point it's probably easier to just create a new clone of that repo in another directory, check out otherbranch, and then add and push your changes there - in that order.